# Is this a native iOS design?

Tags: android, ios

I have a question regarding this design:

[image]

Is this a native iOS design? I'm fairly new to iOS, so I don't know if this is native iOS or not. It does look to me it's Android layout that would need some customization to look the same on iOS. Am I correct?

Would anyone be able to point what would be the items native to Android that don't exist (would require customization) on iOS?

I got a nice answer from Duncan C on this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660005/how-to-mimic-android-bar-on-ios

But now I'd like to validate the whole layout in order to be better prepared. And also, I'd like to know the impacts it could have on my users to use an Android layout on an iOS application.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not an UX question, but a question related to different OS and its implementation

Comment: @Devin I understand you could flag it as broad, but not off-topic. I am concerned about the impacts this layout would have on my iOS users. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking what "Native Design" is, but you're focusing on the wrong question. Designs can be shared, replicated, and evolved across different platforms, adopting different design patterns. You probably want to ask how to best design elements for each ecosystem.

To answer your question though, if you are asking what part of the UI can be implemented with the stock library options, then yes, that nav bar is different. Android's [tabbar](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html) is visually different than [iOS's](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/tab-bars/).

Duncan C is right in that each platform should different, in that they have their own style guides. When he says "create a native app design for both platforms", he means use their own guidelines to build the app around how a user would regularly interact with other apps on their phone.

If you want to see what exists and what doesn't in each ecosystem, read up on their guides:

Android guide [here](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html). iOS guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apart from the bar what else can't be implemented with stock library options? I thought the hamburger was the same case. All options I've seen require a 3rd party component.

Comment: Read the guidelines for a full comprehensive list, but there's nothing wrong with using third party components, probably every single popular app uses them. I can't easily give examples right now, but if you compare the Facebook app on Android and iOS, you could probably see lots of similarities, but also some differences (which is where the stuff I mentioned earlier come into play). One major UI difference is that Android designs don't require a back button as there is back button on the phone.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the hamburger is not a standard iOS control.